# What does the cd /etc command do?

Tags: command-line, cd-command

I was asked the question "what does the `cd /etc` command do?". This is my answer:

> This command `cd /etc` changes directory to the directory specified after the slash `/`. The `/etc` refers to a folder in the root called `etc`. 
>   If the linux user was inside the `/etc` folder, typing `cd /` would bring the user to the root.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What if /etc is a symlink?

Answer (score 4):

The command

```
cd /etc
```

will change the current directory to "/etc" - i.e. the `etc` directory in the root (or `/`) directory.

In your answer the part about "after the slash" is wrong and the part about "if the user were in..." is right but irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consult the manual page for a shell (e.g. `man bash` or `man sh`) for a precise definition of the semantics of `cd` to work on – depending on the audience for your answer, there are some special cases which your wording does not consider. Even so, `cd /etc` changes to the directory called `/etc`. It does **not** "change to the directory specified after the slash", as (strictly read) this would imply that it would change to a subdirectory "etc" located beneath the current directory.